# The simplest way to convert a long date format to YY/MM/DD HTML

Tags: html, datetime, mongoose-schema

I'm new in web development.

my problem is:
how to disaply in html a date in simple format **dd/mm/yy**
instead of **Fri Sep 01 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Israel Daylight Time)**

I'm trying to create a crud api using mongoose.

I have a **schema model**,
one of the fileds is a filed of type date:

`joinDate: {type: Date, required: true}`

in the **controller**:
post- `program.joinDate= req.body.joinDate;`
get-

```
Program.find((err, docs) => {
    res.render("program/list", {
        list: docs
    });
});
```

in the **view**:  `<td>{{this.joinDate}}</td>`

My question: The easy and fast way to convert the long format to short and cleraly format.
I saw some solutions but I think they are too complex and outdated.

If you have any idea for me I would be happy:)
thank's you!

Comment: are you using Angular ?

Comment: No. I'm using .hbs pages with node.js mongoose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often use [mongoose virtual](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html) + [moments](https://momentjs.com/docs/) for this.

```
eventSchema.virtual('joinDate_formatted').get(function () {

return moment(joinDate).calendar({
  sameDay: 'h:mm A',
  nextDay: '[Tomorrow] h:mm A',
  nextWeek: 'dddd',
  lastDay: '[Yesterday] h:mm A',
  lastWeek: '[Last] dddd',
  sameElse: 'DD/MM/YYYY h:mm A'

}); //Above shows in calendar format but u can do whatever u want in moment
});
```

When u do any find on the collection, you will get a joinDate_formatted which u can use on your front end.

Comment: It depends on what you do. E.g. I create a virtual because I use that for rendering in my website and my mobile apps. Within the collection, it still remains as mongoose date format. If you have e.g. creation date, updated date, join date, of course u will need to have 3 different virtual.

Comment: same time, please look at mongoose-lean-virtual, you will very soon need to install that when u use .lean() queries.